# ng-click doesn't work in ionic ion-item tag

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I'm working on a meteo mobile app with ionic and I'm unable to make ng-click='getfp(item)' works in the first ion-item tag. It is supposed to call the getfp function in PrevisionCTRL but the console.log is not even printing anything.

I know there is some stackoverflow about this issues using buttons, I've tried some of them without sucess. So I'm not sure the source of the problem is the same.

Any help would be appreciated

view html:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title>Météo: {{city}}, France</ion-nav-title>
  <!-- if city in db-->
  <ion-content>

      <ion-item ng-if="cityDefined"  ng-repeat="item in prevision.list" class="row" ng-class="{row_active: $index==0}" ng-click='getfp(item)'>

        <div class="temperature">{{Math.round(item.temp.day)}}°C</div>
        <div class="date" >
          <strong>{{item.dt*1000 | date:'EEE'}}</strong>
          {{item.dt*1000 | date:'dd/MM'}}
        </div>
        <div class="wind">Vent: {{item.speed}} Km/h </div>
        <i class="icon-{{item.weather[0].main.toLowerCase() }}"></i>

      </ion-item>

  </ion-content> <!--city not in db-->
  <ion-content >
    <div ng-if="!cityDefined" class="padding cityUndefinded" >
      <p>Désolé, le nom de la ville entrée n'est pas dans la banque de données.</p>

      <p>Veuillez entrer une autre ville, puis faire une selection dans la liste présentant les villes disponibles.</p>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[])

  .controller('PrevisionCtrl',['$scope','$state','$ionicLoading','$http','$stateParams',function ($scope,$state,$ionicLoading,$http,$stateParams){
    // variable pour verifier si la ville existe
    $scope.cityDefined = false;

    console.log("$scope.cityDefined",$scope.cityDefined);
    console.log("$stateParams.city",$stateParams.city);

    //url d'open weather pour les infos quotidiennes dans laquelle on passe la ville en param
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=" + $stateParams.city + "&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=f5fbf26393c3d7c7c8f87dd6dc22b14b";

    // on affiche le chargement le temps de charger les prévisions
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Chargement...'
    });

    //on fait un http sur l'url d'openweathermap.org
    $http.get(url)
      .then(
        function(res){
          $scope.prevision = res.data;
          // on verifie que la ville cherchée existe en comparant la ville de la requete et de la reponse
          if($scope.prevision.city.name == $stateParams.city){
            console.log("$scope.prevision.city.name == $stateParams.city",$scope.prevision.city.name == $stateParams.city);
            $scope.city = $stateParams.city;
            $scope.cityDefined = true;
            console.log($scope.prevision.city.name);
            console.log("$scope.cityDefined",$scope.cityDefined);
            console.log("$stateParams.city",$stateParams.city);

          }
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        },
        function(res){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          console.log(res.message);
        }
      );

    $scope.Math = Math;

    $scope.getfp = function(row){
      // on appelle la vue prévision en passant la ville en paramètre
      $state.go('PrevisionFull', {row: row, city:$stateParams.city});
      console.log(row);
    }

  }])

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  .controller('PrevisionFullCtrl',['$scope','$state','$stateParams',function ($scope,$state,$stateParams){

    $scope.row = $stateParams.row;



  }]);
```

Comment: where you associated controller to the template ?, like : `ng-controller="PrevisionCtrl"`?

Comment: Hi yes it is associated in the app.js file, it seems that it is working now

Answer (score 0):

If it can help others, It seems that I was able to make it work finaly after modifying it to:

view html

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-title>Météo: {{city}}, France</ion-nav-title>
  <!-- if city in db-->
  <ion-content>


    <ion-item ng-if="cityDefined"  ng-repeat="item in prevision.list" class="row" ng-class="{row_active: $index==0}" ng-click='getfp(item)'>

      <div class="temperature">{{Math.round(item.temp.day)}}°C</div>
      <div class="date" >
        <strong>{{item.dt*1000 | date:'EEE'}}</strong>
        {{item.dt*1000 | date:'dd/MM'}}
      </div>
      <div class="wind">Vent: {{item.speed}} Km/h </div>
      <i class="icon-{{item.weather[0].main.toLowerCase() }}"></i>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller

```
  .controller('PrevisionCtrl',['$scope','$state','$ionicLoading','$http','$stateParams',function ($scope,$state,$ionicLoading,$http,$stateParams){
    // variable pour verifier si la ville existe
    $scope.cityDefined = false;

    console.log("$scope.cityDefined",$scope.cityDefined);
    console.log("$stateParams.city",$stateParams.city);

    //url d'open weather pour les infos quotidiennes dans laquelle on passe la ville en param
    url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=" + $stateParams.city + "&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=f5fbf26393c3d7c7c8f87dd6dc22b14b";

    // on affiche le chargement le temps de charger les prévisions
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Chargement...'
    });

    //on fait un http sur l'url d'openweathermap.org
    $http.get(url)
      .then(
        function(res){
          $scope.prevision = res.data;
          // on verifie que la ville cherchée existe en comparant la ville de la requete et de la reponse
          if($scope.prevision.city.name == $stateParams.city){
            console.log("$scope.prevision.city.name == $stateParams.city",$scope.prevision.city.name == $stateParams.city);
            $scope.city = $stateParams.city;
            $scope.cityDefined = true;
            console.log($scope.prevision.city.name);
            console.log("$scope.cityDefined",$scope.cityDefined);
            console.log("$stateParams.city",$stateParams.city);

          }
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        },
        function(res){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
          console.log(res.message);
        }
      );

    $scope.Math = Math;

    $scope.getfp = function(item){
      // on appelle la vue prévision en passant la ville en paramètre
      $state.go('PrevisionFull', {row: item, city:$stateParams.city});
      console.log(item);
    }

  }])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem at a certain time. Since then, I haven't used `ng-click` and `ng-if` on same element. Please, try without `ng-if` on `ion-item`. If it works, wrap the content from `ion-item` into `div` and add `ng-click` on it.

See below:

```
<ion-item ng-if="cityDefined"  ng-repeat="item in prevision.list" class="row" ng-class="{row_active: $index==0}">
<div ng-click='getfp(item)'>
  <div class="temperature">{{Math.round(item.temp.day)}}°C</div>
  <div class="date" >
    <strong>{{item.dt*1000 | date:'EEE'}}</strong>
    {{item.dt*1000 | date:'dd/MM'}}
  </div>
  <div class="wind">Vent: {{item.speed}} Km/h </div>
  <i class="icon-{{item.weather[0].main.toLowerCase() }}"></i>
</div>
```

I hope to help you with my above solution.